# Why is Leakage Current Important when a MOSFET switch is "ON?"

Tags: current, mosfet, integrated-circuit

Referencing [ADG5206](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG5206_5207.pdf). ADI has specs for Drainage Current at the Source and Drain when the switch is OFF. They also have channel leakage for Source and Drain when the switch is ON.

Why is it important to have specifications for leakage current when the switch is ON? Where does this leakage go? Does it simply get consumed within the MOSFET?

Also, I understand why it would be important to have leakage specs when the switch is OFF; however, how much of a difference does it make when the values are so minimal?

I am not designing anything as of yet, simply doing some research. I have found a few App Notes and am still not fully understanding. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datasheet asks you to refer to figure 34.

[image]

Appears as though they mean the maximum current for the differential across the open switches +/-10V.

This is important because the current across the open switches or to the power supplies can represent an error in a precision analog signal. The typical current is fairly high even at room temperature (20pA typical and 600pA over the industrial temperature range). If your signal is 100uA then 600pA represents a 6ppm error.